# How to debug specific build variant of Android Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

If I create `Android Application` debug configuration and will use it, then everything is ok and IntelliJ IDEA by default uses `debug` build type from build.gradle.
But I want to debug specific build variant (flavor and build type). For example, flavor name is `Cabby` and build type if `mock`. I create debug configuration like this:

[image: Cabby Mock Gradle debug configuration]

Then I start debugging this configuration. Gradle tasks `assembleCabbyMock` and `installCabbyMock` are successfully executed and then I see this:

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is `Build Variants` tool window under `View->Tool Windows` where you can choose build variant.

Also there is `Build Variants` docked view on the lower left side of IntelliJ IDEA window.

Comment: It is under 'View' menu